# Maximum elongation or compression when the blocks have the Velocity of centre of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

Suppose there are 2 blocks of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ ($m_1$>$m_2$) connected by spring and are moving in opposite direction with velocities $v_1$ and $v_2$ ($v_2$>$v_1$) respectively.

The maximum elongation or compression of the spring is when the blocks have the velocity of the centre of mass.

But I think that max elongation or compression would be when their velocities are zero.

Please explain where I am going wrong??

Comment: You might want to refer to:https://9to5science.com/how-why-is-spring-compression-maximum-when-the-two-blocks-have-equal-velocities

Answer (score 1):

Both views are essentially correct. Max elongation or compression will be when the *relative* velocity of the two masses is zero, but then both masses will have the velocity of the centre of mass.

Answer (score 0):

starting with the equation of motions

$$m_1\,a_1=k\,(x_2-x_1-L):=k\,x_s\\
m_2\,a_2=-k\,(x_2-x_1-L):=-k\,x_s$$

where $~x_s~$ is the spring elongation.

the acceleration of the center of mass $~a_c~$ is

$$a_c=\frac{m_1\,a_1+m_2\,a_2}{m_1+m2}=\frac{k\,x_s(m_1-m_2)}{m_1+m_2}$$

solving this equation for $~x_s=x_2-x_1-L~$

$$x_s=\frac{a_c}{k}\,\frac{m_1+m_2}{m_1-m_2}\quad ,m_1 > m_2$$
hence: the spring compression $~x_2-x_1~$  is  equal $~L~$   if the velocity of the center of mass $~v_c=a_c\,t~$ is qual zero.